# determining which functions are defined programmatically

Tags: racket

I'd like to replace calls to specific set of functions to my implementations if available, for instance:

```
(define (call-my-fn f . args)
  (cond [(eq? f append) (apply my-append args)]))
```

All of my implementations are in a separate file and I don't want to keep adding to the `cond` clause. Is there a way I can write something like:

```
(require "my-fns.rkt")
(define (call-my-fn f . args)
  (cond [(is-defined? f "my-fns.rkt") (apply "my-version-of-f" args)]))
```

Comment: This blog post by Greg Hendershott might help you: [_Fallback when required function not available_](https://www.greghendershott.com/2014/06/fallback-when-required-function-not-available.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`dynamic-require`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Module_Names_and_Loading.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._dynamic-require%29%29) can be used to query a provided variable in other modules dynamically. The third argument of `dynamic-require` controls what should happen when the queried variable doesn't exist, so you can do something like:

```
;; lib.rkt

#lang racket

(provide foo bar)
(define foo #f)
(define (bar x) x)
```

```
;; client.rkt

#lang racket

(define does-not-exist (gensym))
(eq? (dynamic-require "lib.rkt" 'foo (λ () does-not-exist)) does-not-exist) ; #t
(eq? (dynamic-require "lib.rkt" 'bar (λ () does-not-exist)) does-not-exist) ; #t
(eq? (dynamic-require "lib.rkt" 'baz (λ () does-not-exist)) does-not-exist) ; #f
```

One might try to simplify the above to

```
;; client.rkt

#lang racket

(dynamic-require "lib.rkt" 'foo (λ () #f)) ; #f
(dynamic-require "lib.rkt" 'bar (λ () #f)) ; #<procedure:bar>
(dynamic-require "lib.rkt" 'baz (λ () #f)) ; #f
```

This would work if you know that all provided identifiers are not bound to `#f`. But if that's not the case, it would give an incorrect result as shown above. The solution workarounds the problem by returning a fresh unique symbol `does-not-exist` which is only `eq?` to itself. Then, we can use `eq?` to test if the returned value is `does-not-exist`. If it is, then we know for sure that the identifier is not provided.

Comment: Would it be considered bad practice to return `'does-not-exist` instead of a unique symbol given by `gensym`?

Comment: If you return `'does-not-exist`, then in case `foo` has the value `'does-not-exist`, it would fail. The point of `gensym` is to be completely foolproof regardless of any value `foo` might have, because it's unique.